# Issue with ember-power-select, wrong display, but good data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, display

I have a small issue with ember-power-select. In a form, I want to set a value to either **Logical** or **Physical**, so I decided to use ember-power-select. It work correctly, but when I change the value on the form with ember-power-select, the display is still the same, by that I mean that I stay on **Logical**, even if the value is **Physical**.
Here is the template:

```js
{{#form.element label=(t 'type')}}
  {{#power-select
    selected=selectedType
    searchEnabled=false
    options=allType
    onchange=(action (mut zone.type))
    placeholder=(t 'type_zone')
    as |type|}}
  {{/power-select}}
{{/form.element}}
```

And here is the component:

```js
allType: ['Logical', 'Physical'],
selectedType: 'Logical'
```

And the model:

```js
type: DS.attr('string')
```

Everything related to this power-select is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected=selected` change this to `selected=selectedType`.

you need to provide `selectedType` as selected for maintaining the selected properties.

---

Try this, we removed `selectedType` and used `zone.type` as selected type.

`selected=zone.type` and `onchange=(action (mut zone.type))`
Here `onchange` action will set the selected value to `zone.type`. so you need to have `selected=zone.type` only then selected changes will persist.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it too, but the power-select stay on **Logical**. The value of type is undefined if I don't touch anything, and if I click on **Physical**, the value change to physical, but the display still show **Logical**. And I cannot change the value to **Logical**

Comment: If I change `onchange` from `(action (mut zone.type))` to `(action (mut selectedType))`, the display is good, but of course the value of **zone.type** stay undefined.

Comment: Thank you that work perfectly, should have tried it earlier!